# How to draw highcharts based on the value of a checkbox in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, highcharts, ng-controller

#### Second controller not working in AngularJS

I want to create an application in which when you click on a checkbox, a [highcharts](/questions/tagged/highcharts)is drawn. The [highcharts](/questions/tagged/highcharts)reads the data from a controller.
But first, I am just trying to draw [highcharts](/questions/tagged/highcharts)and checkboxes in an [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)app. But I am unable to draw checkboxes.
Can you please let me know what's wrong with my code? I am a beginner in [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs).

```js
angular.module('myModule', [])
  // Directive for generic chart, pass in chart options
  .directive('hcChart',  function () {
    return  {
      restrict:   'E',
      template:   '<div></div>',
      scope: {
        options:   '='
      },
      link:   function (scope, element) {
        Highcharts.chart(element[0], scope.options);
      }
    };
    console.log(element[0], scope.options)
  })
  // Directive for pie charts, pass in title and data only
  .directive('hcPieChart',  function () {
    return  {
      restrict:   'E',
      template:   '<div></div>',
      scope: {
        title:   '@',
        data:   '='
      },
      link:   function (scope, element) {
        Highcharts.chart(element[0], {
          chart: {
            type:   'pie'
          },
          title: {
            text: scope.title
          },
          plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              allowPointSelect:  true,
              cursor:   'pointer',
              dataLabels: {
                enabled:  true,
                format:   '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
              }
            }
          },
          series: [{
            data: scope.data
          }]
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    // Sample options for first chart
    $scope.chartOptions  = {
      title: {
        text:   'Temperature data'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan',  'Feb',  'Mar',  'Apr',  'May',  'Jun',
          'Jul',  'Aug',  'Sep',  'Oct',  'Nov',  'Dec'
        ]
      },

      series: [{
        data: [29.9,  71.5,  106.4,  129.2,  144.0,  176.0,  135.6,  148.5,  216.4,  194.1,  95.6,  54.4]
      }]
    };

    // Sample data for pie chart
    $scope.pieData  = [{
      name:   "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
      y:  56.33
    }, {
      name:   "Chrome",
      y:  24.03,
      sliced:  true,
      selected:  true
    }, {
      name:   "Firefox",
      y:  10.38
    }, {
      name:   "Safari",
      y:  4.77
    }, {
      name:   "Opera",
      y:  0.91
    }, {
      name:   "Proprietary or Undetectable",
      y:  0.2
    }]
  }])
  .controller('checkboxCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.arrlist = [{
      "userid": 1,
      "name": "Suresh"
    }, {
      "userid": 2,
      "name": "Rohini"
    }, {
      "userid": 3,
      "name": "Praveen"
    }];
    $scope.checkoptions = function(choice) {
      var details = [];
      angular.forEach(choice, function(value, key) {
        if (choice[key].checked) {
          details.push(choice[key].userid);
        }
      });
      if (details.length > 0)
        $scope.msg = 'Selected Values: ' + details.toString();
      else
        $scope.msg = 'Please choose an option';

      if (details.indexOf(1) > -1)
        $scope.msg = $scope.msg + 'UserId:1';
      if (details.indexOf(2) > -1)
        $scope.msg = $scope.msg + 'UserId:2';
      if (details.indexOf(3) > -1)
        $scope.msg = $scope.msg + 'UserId:3';

    };
  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myModule">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Highcharts directive demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="highchartsapp.js"></script>

  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <hc-chart options="chartOptions">Placeholder for generic chart</hc-chart>
    <hc-pie-chart title="Browser usage" data="pieData">Placeholder for pie chart</hc-pie-chart>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="checkboxCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="user in arrlist">
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{user.userid}}" ng-model="user.checked" />
      <label>{{user.name}}</label>
    </div><br />

    <input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Submit" ng-click="checkoptions(arrlist)" /><br /><br />
    <span style="color:Red">{{msg}}</span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are unable to draw checkboxes? What do you mean when you say the second controller isn't working?

Comment: My issue has been resolved. I need to know how can I draw highcharts based on the value of a checkbox in angularjs framework.

Comment: What do you have problem with exactly?

Comment: the question exactly is my problem